# The solution for Failed to send close message

Tags: python, opencv, youtube

I am using opencv to load a live video from youtube, but the program terminates in the middle with a "Failed to send close message".

I would like to keep getting images 24 hours a day, all the time, and I would like to know what is the best way to do this.

```
import pafy
import cv2

url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_9OBhtLA9Ig"
video = pafy.new(url)
best = video.getbest(preftype="mp4")

capture = cv2.VideoCapture(best.url)
while True:
    grabbed, frame = capture.read()
    # ...
```

Comment: *Video not available* - [edit] your question and show the current and desired results.

Comment: @Marco Aurelio Femandez ReyesSorry, the correct URL is here. url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DjdUEyjx8GM"

Comment: Failed to send close message is a bug in ffmpeg when it closes. It has nothing to do with closing itself.